# Browser still leaking real user agent

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

I am writing a privacy extension which requires me to spoof the user agent property of the browser aka navigator.userAgent (yes I already know about the User-Agent HTTP header and have already dealt with that).

My issue is that a page might not just have a main frame but also a variable about of iframes as well. In my manifest file i am using all_frames: true to inject my content script into all frames and match_about_blank: true to inject into frames with a url of "about:blank".

I am using [BrowserLeaks](https://browserleaks.com/javascript) to test my extension it seems to spoof the user agent correctly using the window option but when using the iframe.contentWindow method it shows the real user agent.

I believe it might be because the iframe is sandboxed and you are not allowed to inject into sandboxed iframes. This would be a huge problem since sites could evade extensions and deny them access to a sandboxed iframe.

This is the error I get on Chromium:

> Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

From [Chrome Developer](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

match_about_blank:

> Optional. Whether to insert the content script on about:blank and about:srcdoc. Content scripts will only be injected on pages when their inherit URL is matched by one of the declared patterns in the matches field. The inherit URL is the URL of the document that created the frame or window.
> Content scripts cannot be inserted in sandboxed frames.
>
> Defaults to false.

Or perhaps the script is running in all iframes including the sandboxed ones but the script is not running quickly enough i.e. not run_at: document_start.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts)

match_about_blank:

> match_about_blank is supported in Firefox from version 52. Note that in Firefox, content scripts won't be injected into empty iframes at "document_start" even if you specify that value in run_at.

My title says chrome extension however it is going to be for Firefox too. I posted documentation from both MDN and Chrome since their wording is different. On Chrome when I test this on say github.com I get errors regarding sandboxing on iframe however on Firefox I get no errors of such, however it still doesn't spoof the property inside the iframe like I want it to. Any ideas?

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Shape Shifter",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Anti browser fingerprinting web extension. Generates randomised values for HTTP request headers and javascript API's.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/crossed_eye_16x16.png",
        "32": "icons/crossed_eye_32x32.png",
        "48": "icons/crossed_eye_48x48.png",
        "128": "icons/crossed_eye_128x128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Shape Shifter",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/crossed_eye_16x16.png",
            "32": "icons/crossed_eye_32x32.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["js/inject.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/lib/seedrandom.min.js",
        "js/random.js",
        "js/api/document.js",
        "js/api/navigator.js",
        "js/api/canvas.js",
        "js/api/history.js",
        "js/api/battery.js",
        "js/api/audio.js",
        "js/api/element.js"
    ]
}
```

inject.js (My content script)

```
console.log("Content Script Running ...");

function inject(filePath, seed) {
  // Dynamically create a script
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  // Give the script a seed value to use for spoofing
  script.setAttribute("data-seed", seed);

  // Give the script a url to the javascript code to run
  script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filePath);

  // Listen for the script loading event
  script.onload = function() {
    // Remove the script from the page so the page scripts don't see it
    this.remove();
  };

  // Add the script tag to the DOM
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

function getSeed(origin) {
    // Get a Storage object
    var storage = window.sessionStorage;

    // Try to get a seed from sessionStorage
    var seed = storage.getItem(origin);

    // Do we already have a seed in storage for this origin or not?
    if (seed === null) {
        // Initialise a 32 byte buffer
        seed = new Uint8Array(32);

        // Fill it with cryptographically random values
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(seed);

        // Save it to storage
        storage.setItem(origin, seed);
    }

    return seed;
}

var seed = getSeed(window.location.hostname);

inject("js/lib/seedrandom.min.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Seed Random ...");

inject("js/random.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Random ...");

inject("js/api/document.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Document API ...");

inject("js/api/navigator.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Navigator API ...");

inject("js/api/canvas.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Canvas API ...");

inject("js/api/history.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected History API ...");

inject("js/api/battery.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Battery API ...");

inject("js/api/audio.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Audio API ...");

inject("js/api/element.js", seed);
console.log("[INFO] Injected Element API ...");
```

Comment: When you spoof a page object you run a page script, not a content script, which is why the iframe sandbox restrictions apply. I think there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @wOxxOm That is really unfortunate. So if a page wants to get the real value of the user agent they can just make a iframe sandboxed and then my extension can't do anything about it? That makes my extension pointless. Is there no way around this? Previously with legacy firefox addons you could just set the userAgent preference value but with the new web extensions you can't do this anymore. I guess making a privacy extension with web extensions is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] allowing us to duplicate the problem and include *exactly* how you're testing. While *we want to help*, to do so we would have to recreate code you already have, even then it'd be just a **guess** at what you're doing. With code, it's much easier to help you. Without code, the effort required to do more than make educated guesses is quite high. As you know, this is a tricky situation, which, if solvable, will require a hack and testing. Including a [mcve] makes it **much** more likely you get an actual answer. So, please help us to help you and include a [mcve].

Comment: @Makyen My bad. I have edited the question to include my manifest.json and my content script.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issues in the following way:

From my content script ...

```
var UAScript = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); "+
               "for (i=0; i<iFrames.length; i++) try { Object.defineProperty(iFrames[i].contentWindow.clientInformation, 'userAgent', { value:'Custom' }); } catch(e) {} }); "+
               "try { Object.defineProperty(clientInformation, 'userAgent', { value:'Custom' }); } catch(e) {}";
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent = UAScript;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

This changes both the userAgent on the document, plus the iFrames after the DOMContentLoaded triggers.

Question is ..., is there a better way of doing this?

(Because you can still get around this spoof by adding an iframe inside an iframe, etc.)